# Add indexes in MySQL for fields used in SELECT not WHERE, improves something?

Tags: mysql, indexing

We know that we index a column to improve performance when we filter by that column in a WHERE statement, but if we do something like:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  SUM(principal_lent) AS lifetime_total_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), principal_lent, 0)) AS yearly_total_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), principal_lent, 0)) AS quarterly_total_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), principal_lent, 0)) AS monthly_total_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), principal_lent, 0)) AS current_month_total_loans,
  COUNT(id) AS lifetime_num_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), 1, 0)) AS yearly_num_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), 1, 0)) AS quarterly_num_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), 1, 0)) AS monthly_num_loans,
  SUM(IF(loan_created_at >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) and loan_created_at <= NOW(), 1, 0)) AS current_month_num_loans
FROM loans
GROUP BY customer_id
```

The field customer_id is a FK so it is indexed.

If I index loan_created_at, it will make any difference? How can I improve performance?
Thanks

Comment: Indexing really only helps you in the WHERE clause and in JOIN conditions (if you are joining on a field that's not a PK or FK). In your case to speed things up I'd recommend storing the data in another table that you update daily with a cron job.

Comment: The only way I could see to potentially improve performance here is to have a nightly job which (running early morning  identifies the loan age/Group), then you don't have to do all the calculations on the query each time it's run; but once each night.  Any "New/Null values" would be newly created loans and fall into the current month.  Alternatively you could generate a table with the results of the query each night and UNION & Sum in anything "new" that way the overhead is only on the new records.

Comment: There is one question that needs to be asked: when you run the above query, what is the response time that you get? A second question is: Why to you look for data back without any limit (I ,mean, it looks reasonable to say that you would only look for data that is at most 1 year old, or 6 months old, or any other period). If you really need to look back to the beginning of history, you should consider "cooking" some of your data as @xQbert suggests.

Comment: This is the SELECT of a MySQL view we are using, in which we are filtering by customer (the limit) and for 90k rows it takes 1.2 sec to query. I think we will go for the daily cron job and put it in a static table. Thanks guys

Comment: How many rows in `loans`?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE loans`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any filtering, and with any other things that might be useful, that query will be performed via a table scan.  That means, all rows will be read in whatever order is convenient to the optimizer.  There may be a temp table and a sort to perform the `GROUP BY`.  That could be avoided only if the `PRIMARY KEY` *starts* with `customer_id`, which I doubt.

Do you really want `DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL...`?  That starts in the middle of some day in the past.  Run the same query a minute later, and the values may increase or decrease.

If you were happy with calendar days, then change `NOW()` to `CURRENT_DATE()`.  At that point, you could, perhaps, build a summary table of counts and subtotals for each day.  Update that table each night to reflect yesterday's data.  Then change this 'report' query to use the summary table.  It is likely to be much faster.

With more information about filtering, and the `CREATE TABLE`, we might be able to give more specifics.